# SQL Query to calculate the hours between two dates grouped by days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to write an SQL query for the following scenario.

I am having start date as 2020-01-10 13:00:00.347 and end date as 2020-01-12 02:00:00.347, so I need data grouped as

```
Day              Hours
----             -----
10-01-2020       11
11-01-2020       24
12-01-2020       2.30
```

which means 11 hours was for the first date and 24 hours in second day and 2.3 hours on 3rd day.

What will the most Efficient SQL query to fetch the data in the above-mentioned format?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ? Also, show the data at the begining(before the query)?

Comment: Why 02:00:00.347 => 2.30 hrs?

Comment: Generate dates list in CTE. Calculate the length of thу intersection in hours.

Comment: Thanks @Roy for the response but, the TIMESTAMPDIFF() or the DATEDIFF() as in SQL returns just a single value which will be the total count of the unit specified, it doesnot group the result day wise.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are so many downvotes.  Some may find that the question may not be quite as clear as it could be, but downvotes don't help a new user understand how to improve anything.  (And I find the question quite clear.)

Comment: @Akina,
That means that the specified time range has 2:30 (2 hours and 30  mins) minutes on the day 12-01-2020. My intention is to show the Total hours split across each day separately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff downvote means more than just is the question clear...

Comment: @GordonLinoff In a half of the cases the downvote means "try searching before asking, and you may not need to ask at all"... or the same but "read user manual". Anycase this means that downvoter think that the question quality is low - and not necessarily by form.

Comment: @Akina I'm fairly certain that with over 900,000 rep gained over eight years on the site, Gordon is familiar with how the site works.

Comment: @Kev well from the comment above it looks like that is not so... I am just fine with the fact that someone learns something later... Having a lot of points is not equal 
 to "I know it all".

Comment: @VBoka see my previous comment.

Comment: @Kev sorry, I see only one comment here that is from you, and to that one I have answered... My answer is to your comment...

Comment: What's the largest gap you could have between the 2 times? are these values coming from a table, or 2 variables?

Comment: Also, how do you get `2.3` for `2020-01-12 02:00:00.347`? `.347` seconds is `0.00000009638883` of an hour, so I would expect the final row's value to be `2.00`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a recursive CTE to break the dates into ranges:

```
with recursive cte as (
       select start_date as day_start,
              (case when date(start_date) = date(end_date) then end_date else date(start_date) + interval 1 day end) as day_end,
              end_date
       from (select cast('2020-01-10 13:00:00.347' as datetime) as start_date,
                    cast('2020-01-12 02:00:00.347' as datetime) as end_date
            ) t
       union all
       select day_end,
              (case when date(day_end) = date(end_date) then end_date else date(day_end) + interval 1 day end) as day_end,
              end_date
       from cte
       where day_end <> end_date
     )
select day_start, day_end,
       timestampdiff(second, day_start, day_end) / (60 * 60)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c81a8a73c0a825ca8c2e454cc6caeb7) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
with cte as (
       select start_date as day_start,
              (case when cast(start_date as date) = cast(end_date as date) then end_date else dateadd(day, 1, cast(start_date as date)) end) as day_end,
              end_date
       from (select cast('2020-01-10 13:00:00.347' as datetime) as start_date,
                    cast('2020-01-12 02:00:00.347' as datetime) as end_date
            ) t
       union all
       select day_end,
              (case when cast(day_end as date) = cast(end_date as date) then end_date else dateadd(day, 1, day_end) end) as day_end,
              end_date
       from cte
       where day_end <> end_date
     )
select day_start, day_end,
       datediff(second, day_start, day_end) / (60.0 * 60)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d0d3282ac3703102d331e9a1fc3bdd8) is this db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon this is what I had been looking for, but in SQL. I will try to convert this into SQL and let you know the result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just tried running this in SQL but it doesn't work

Comment: This is maybe one more reason why the question should have more details. What version of MySQL do you use ?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Ok, you have probably made a misake... No problem. One more thing, @Akina asked you a good question in the comments. Please check it and update your question with explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Sure VBoka will update the question. And thanks @akina for correcting me :)

Comment: *"What will the most Efficient SQL query"* Realise that the OP tagged MySQL previously, but using an rCTE process for SQL Server will *not* be the most efficient method if they ever need to deal with more than a couple of days, or large sets.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP has asked for the most effecient method, and rCTE's are [known to perform poorly](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/), a more efficient approach would be using a Tally.

This isn't anywhere near as easy to read for a beginner, however, does get the results you are after (with the exception of that `2020-01-12` has a value of `2.0` not `2.3`, as your math is clearly wrong there):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (StartDate datetime,
                            EndDate datetime);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (StartDate,
                           EndDate)
VALUES('2020-01-10T13:00:00.347','2020-01-12T02:00:00.347'),
      ('2020-01-14T17:24:41.243','2020-01-19T09:17:12.997');
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate)+1) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days enough?
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I,CONVERT(date,YT.StartDate)) AS [Date],
           CASE WHEN T.I = 0 THEN YT.StartDate ELSE DATEADD(DAY, T.I,CONVERT(date,YT.StartDate)) END AS StartingDateTime,
           CASE WHEN LEAD(T.I) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.StartDate ORDER BY T.I) IS NULL THEN YT.EndDate ELSE DATEADD(DAY, T.I+1,CONVERT(date,YT.StartDate)) END AS EndingDateTime
    FROM Tally T
         JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, YT.StartDate, YT.EndDate))
SELECT D.[Date],
       (DATEDIFF(SECOND,D.StartingDateTime,D.EndingDateTime) * 1.0) / 60 / 60 AS [Hours]
FROM Dates D;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61d076f7919e4715230cae18aa873e7f)