# Count hours within intervals grouped by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl` with the following sample code:

```
declare @tbl table
(
Date1 datetime,
Date2 datetime
)

insert into @tbl
values
('2020-06-03 11:00','2020-06-03 14:00'),
('2020-06-03 19:00','2020-06-04 01:00'),
('2020-06-04 11:00','2020-06-04 14:00')

select * from @tbl
```

I want to output the number of hours that where spent between the two columns.

Sample desired output:

```
Day        | Hours
2020-06-03 | 8
2020-06-04 | 4
```

I tried doing:

```
select sum(datediff(hour,Date1,Date2)) from @tbl
group by cast(Date1 as date)
```

But this doesn't have in mind the interval that crossed the two days, outputting 9 and 3.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generic solution, you can use a recursive CTE to split the time spans into separate days and then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select date1, date1 as date2,
             date2 as enddate, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select date2,
             (case when datediff(day, date1, enddate) = 0 then enddate
                   else dateadd(day, 1, datefromparts(year(date1), month(date1), day(date1)))
              end) as date2,
             enddate, 1 + lev
      from cte
      where date1 < enddate 
     )
select convert(date, date1), sum(datediff(hour, date1, date2))
from cte
group by convert(date, date1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cb6048efc3ffa53cabf419a28216299) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @LeszekMazur . . . Of course it does:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92a9fd010b245f905cfce1bfe048ab7d.

Comment: check: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d00a3b7fd59efcbae83275bfa53c3c7f

Comment: @LeszekMazur . . . Oops, I left in the `lev` condition which I use for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ripping this answer from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59860458/2029983), with a slight difference to aggregate per day instead.

You need to split your values into each day, and then you can `SUM` per day:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, Date1, Date2)+1) FROM @tbl)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days enough?
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I,CONVERT(date,YT.Date1)) AS [Date],
           CASE WHEN T.I = 0 THEN YT.Date1 ELSE DATEADD(DAY, T.I,CONVERT(date,YT.Date1)) END AS StartingDateTime,
           CASE WHEN LEAD(T.I) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Date1 ORDER BY T.I) IS NULL THEN YT.Date2 ELSE DATEADD(DAY, T.I+1,CONVERT(date,YT.Date1)) END AS EndingDateTime
    FROM Tally T
         JOIN @tbl YT ON T.I <= DATEDIFF(DAY, YT.Date1, YT.Date2))
SELECT D.[Date],
       SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR,D.StartingDateTime,D.EndingDateTime)) AS [Hours]
FROM Dates D
GROUP BY D.[Date];
```